# dict from a dict of list

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a Python dictionary with following format:

```
d1 = {'Name':['ABC'], 'Number':['123'], 'Element 1':['1', '2', '3'],
      'Element2':['1','2','3']}
```

Expected output:

```
{'Name': 'ABC', 'Number': '123',
 'Elements': [{'Element 1': '1', 'Element2': '1'},
              {'Element 1': '2', 'Element2': '2'},
              {'Element 1': '3', 'Element2': '3'}]
```

I have tried the following:

```
[{k: v[i] for k, v in d1.items() if i < len(v)}
    for i in range(max([len(l) for l in d1.values()]))]
```

but getting this result:

```
[{'Name': 'ABC', 'Number': '123', 'Element 1': '1', 'Element 2': '1'},
 {'Element 1': '2', 'Element 2': '2'},
 {'Element 1': '3', 'Element 2': '3'}]
```

How can I go from here?

Comment: would be helpful to readers if you also included what happens when you try what you provided

Comment: @avigil added the question, thank you

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend *not* trying to do everything in one line. It's not always more efficient, and almost always less readable if you have any branching logic or nested loops.

Given your dict, we can `pop()` the `Name` and `Number` keys into our new dict. Then

```
output = dict()

d1 = {'Name':['ABC'], 'Number':['123'], 'Element 1':['1', '2', '3'], 'Element2':['1','2','3']}

output["Name"] = d1.pop("Name")
output["Number"] = d1.pop("Number")

print(output)
# prints:
# {'Name': ['ABC'], 'Number': ['123']}

print(d1)
# prints:
# {'Element 1': ['1', '2', '3'], 'Element2': ['1', '2', '3']}
```

Then, we zip all remaining values in the dictionary, and add them to a new list:

```
mylist = []
keys = d1.keys()

for vals in zip(*d1.values()):
    temp_obj = dict(zip(keys, vals))
    mylist.append(temp_obj)

print(mylist)
# prints: 
# [{'Element 1': '1', 'Element2': '1'},
#  {'Element 1': '2', 'Element2': '2'},
#  {'Element 1': '3', 'Element2': '3'}]
```

And finally, assign that to `output["Elements"]`

```
output["Elements"] = mylist
print(output)
# prints:
# {'Name': ['ABC'], 'Number': ['123'], 'Elements': [{'Element 1': '1', 'Element2': '1'}, {'Element 1': '2', 'Element2': '2'}, {'Element 1': '3', 'Element2': '3'}]}
```

---

Since you don't want to hardcode the first two keys,

```
for k, v in d1.items():
    if "element" not in k.lower():
        output[k] = v
```

Or as a dict-comprehension:

```
output = {k: v for k, v in d1.items() if "element" not in k.lower()}
```

Comment: Many thanks for the fast answer, would it be alos possible to not hardcode the key "Name" and "Number"?

Comment: Is it safe to assume the same treatment should be applied to any key not containing `"Element"`? See the latest edit @Volume069

Comment: now the "element" is hardcoded...@Pranav Hosangadi

Comment: @Volume069 Change `if "element" not in k.lower()` to whatever logic you want then

Comment: not sure, how to proceed from this place, but thanks anyways.

Comment: What do you mean? What logic do you want? You said "yes" to _"Is it safe to assume the same treatment should be applied to any key not containing `"Element"`"_, which is what `if "element" not in k.lower()` does. What logic would you use to determine which keys go to the top  level and which keys go to the list?

Comment: Hosangad - this was my question at the first palce...and even if it is safe to asume, it should not be hardcoded...

Comment: @volume069 I can't come up with logic for you because I don't know how your input might change. With the information you've given, this is the best that can be done

Answer (score 0):

use a list of tuples to create the elements list of dictionaries.   Use Convert to build your dictionary item from the tuple.

```
#https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-convert-list-tuples-dictionary/

d1 = {'Name':['ABC'], 'Number':['123'], 'Element 1':['1', '2', '3'],
  'Element2':['1','2','3']}

def Convert(tup, di):
    for a, b in tup:
       di[a]=b
    return di

dict={}
listElements=[]
for key,value in d1.items():
   if isinstance(value,list) and len(value)>1:
       for item in value:
           listElements.append((key,item))
   elif isinstance(value,list) and len(value)==1:
       dict[key]=value[0]
   else:
       dict[key]=value
    
 dict['Elements']=[Convert([(x,y)],{})  for x,y in listElements]
 print(dict)
```

output:

```
 {'Name': 'ABC', 'Number': '123', 'Elements': [{'Element 1': '1'}, {'Element 1': '2'}, {'Element 1': '3'}, {'Element2': '1'}, {'Element2': '2'}, {'Element2': '3'}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to explain step by step:

1. We build `new_d1` variable, that is the dictionary you expect as output and it's initialized as `{'Name': 'ABC', 'Number': '123'}`. For achieving the above, we use comprehension notation taking into account the keys `!=` `'Element'`

   ```
   new_d1 = {key: d1.get(key)[0] for key in filter(lambda x: 'Element' not in x, d1)}
   ```
2. We build `elements` variable, that's a list with the dictionaries matter for us, I mean, the dictionaries we have to manipulate to achieve the expected result. Then `elements` is `[{'Element 1': ['1', '2', '3']}, {'Element2': ['1', '2', '3']}]`.

   ```
   elements = [{key: d1.get(key)} for key in filter(lambda x: 'Element' in x, d1)]
   ```
3. We are going to do a Cartesian product using [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) taking into account each key and each **item of the values** present in `elements`.

   ```
   product = [list(it.product(d.keys(), *d.values())) for d in elements]
   ```
4. Using `zip`, we arrange the data and covert them in dictionary. And finally we create `"Elements"` key in `new_df1`

   ```
   elements_list = [dict(t) for index, t in enumerate(list(zip(*product)))]
   new_d1["Elements"] = elements_list

   print(new_d1)
   ```

***Full code:***

```
import itertools as it

new_d1 = {key: d1.get(key)[0] for key in filter(lambda x: 'Element' not in x, d1)}
elements = [{key: d1.get(key)} for key in filter(lambda x: 'Element' in x, d1)]
product = [list(it.product(d.keys(), *d.values())) for d in elements]
elements_list = [dict(t) for index, t in enumerate(list(zip(*product)))]
new_d1["Elements"] = elements_list
```

Output:

```
{'Elements': [{'Element 1': '1', 'Element2': '1'},
              {'Element 1': '2', 'Element2': '2'},
              {'Element 1': '3', 'Element2': '3'}],
 'Name': 'ABC',
 'Number': '123'}
```